# Login takes more time when there is huge amount of data in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, struts-1, java-6, jboss-4.0.x

Even I increase my datafile size using alter query

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\SYSTEM.DBF' AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE 2048M;
```

It runs fine after increasing the size but it needs restart the server system after every 24 hours. If I don't restart my server system, login takes more time than usual. What is the issue?

Comment: What does the datafile size have to do with login time or requiring server restarts? What is making you restart - just the perception of longer login times? And can you quantify that, and clarify it you're talking about local connections (e.g. SQL\*Plus on the DB server, as sys or normal users) or remotely? Have you looked at the log files to see if that gives you any indication of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you try to connect. you try to login from sqlplus or using virtualmachine or with easyconnect ?

Generally this problems comes from listener or DNS.

The listener can sometimes cause slow connections, and you should try connecting diectly, bypassing the listener.  Bouncing the listener (lsnrctl stop, lsnrctl start) can sometimes fix a slow connection issue

Also note that a slow initial connction may be due to factors outside of Oracle, things like firewalls or entries in the /etc/resolve.conf file. Also, check these files for DNS related connection latency:

eth0 interface (static): IP : 192.168.1.101 SM : 255.255.255.0 GW: 192.168.1.101
DNS: 192.168.1.101

/etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.1.111 hostnamebla.blabla host